# Eliminate numbers from a sentence in Python

Tags: python

I am parsing from a xml file and trying to build a dictionary for every context in the xml. I have done parsing successfully, and now I need to get rid of the stopwords, punctuations and numbers from the string I get.

However, for some reason, I couldn't get rid of the numbers, I have been debugging all night, hope someone could help me with it...

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

I have been checking that the method 'is_number' is working, but I don't why it still could get pass the if statement:

```
if (words[headIndex + index] not in cachedStopWords) and ~isNumber:
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you not using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm

Comment: @Julius, Because the string I am checking may not be unicoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
~isNumber
```

`~` is the [bitwise not operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types). You want the `not` [boolean operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```
>>> ~True
-2
>>> ~False
-1
>>> not True
False
>>> not False
True
```

The bitwise operator will lead to `~isNumber` always being a truthy value (`-1` or `-2`), and so your `if` statement is entered.